# Node.js how can I pass a string or Array that contain arguments as function arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a code in Node.JS that will get an array with values and will pass it to a function but without success..

This is my code:

```
var tmpArr = [];
tmpArr.push('"2015-04-27", "12345", "http://thispage.com/2.html", 1, 1, 0, 0');
tmpArr.push('"2015-04-25", "34567", "http://thispage.com/2.html", 0, 0, 1, 1');
tmpArr.push('"2015-04-25", "34567", "http://thispage.com/2.html", 0, 0, 1, 1');

function reportPages(arr) {
    for (i in arr){
        putPage(arr[i]); //this did not work
    }
}

function reportPages(arr) {
    for (i in arr){
        putPage(eval(arr[i])); //this did not work eater 
    }
}

reportPages(tmpArr)
```

Thanks to all the helpers!

Comment: what happens? do you get an error? what does "does not work" mean exactly?

Comment: Notice that you [shouldn't use `for in` enumerations on arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

Well, an arguments list is no structure that can be represented with plain js. To pass multiple function arguments that are encoded as a string, you'd have to use

```
eval('putPage('+arr[i]+')')
```

or better

```
putPage.apply(null, JSON.parse('['+arr[i]+']'));
```

However, your `putPage` function does not even expect multiple arguments but a single array, so you'd just have to use

```
putPage(JSON.parse('['+arr[i]+']'));
```

I would however recommend to store proper JSON strings or real arrays in your `tmpArr` in the first place, like

```
var tmpArr = [
    ["2015-04-27", "12345", "http://thispage.com/2.html", 1, 1, 0, 0],
    ["2015-04-25", "34567", "http://thispage.com/2.html", 0, 0, 1, 1],
    ["2015-04-25", "34567", "http://thispage.com/2.html", 0, 0, 1, 1]
];
```